# Problema de Posición Usando Tooltip.show() en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Lo que me ocurre es que estoy diseñando un `Form` para recuperación de contraseña a la cual debe ingresar el correo Electrónico, lo que pretendo es que al oprimir el botón `Enviar` se pueda evaluar el string y salga un `Tooltip.show()` si no es correcto.

Mi problema se basa en la ubicación de ese `tooltip` ya que aparece a media pantalla sin intención de mostrarse sobre el `textbox`.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
Form.Texbox : TBCorreoUsu    

 private void BTEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
        {
            Notificacion.IsBalloon = true;
            Notificacion.ShowAlways = true;
            Notificacion.ToolTipTitle = "Alerta";
            Notificacion.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;

            String Correo = TBCorreoUsu.Text;

          Val =  Validar.ValidaciondeCorreo(Correo);
          if (Val == true)
          {
              //Enviar Correo
              MessageBox.Show("El correo Se enviara");
          }
          else {
              Notificacion.Show("El Correo Ingresado no Es Valido o Esta Incompleto", TBCorreoUsu);
              TBCorreoUsu.Focus();

          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias sobrecargas del método `Show` que te permiten situar el Tooltip en la posición que quieras. Prueba con esto:

```
Notificacion.Show("El Correo Ingresado no Es Valido o Esta Incompleto", this, TBCorreoUsu.Location.X, TBCorreoUsu.Location.Y);
```